# Show that $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continous on bounded set [-10, 10]

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I understand that if $f(x)=x^2$ is considered over any interval in general, it follows that it is uniformly continuous. Here's what I've done so far:

Given $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary, we must find a single $\delta>0$ where by $|x-y|<\delta$  $=>$ $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Now $|f(x)-f(y)| = |x^2-y^2|=|x+y||x-y|$

Now, we must find an upper bound on $|x+y|$ and must choose an appropriate $\delta$ such that all values of $x$ considered will fall in the interval $[-10, 10]$.

I believe I may have to use some sort of estimation on $|x+y|$, but I'm not sure what that would look like. I'm new to the concept of uniform convergence, and would greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light on how I might find a respectable $\delta$ in a situation such like the one I've outlined here. Thanks!

Comment: On the interval we have $|x+y| \le |x| + |y| \le 20$.

Comment: Or use that $f'(x)=2x$,so $|f'| \le 20$, so $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks @angryavian I guess I've confused myself of thinking of x and y in terms of a cartesian plane, while they're arbitary values in the interval.

Is this just because the maximum value either x or y could take is 10 (due to the closed interval)?

Comment: Any continuous function on a bounded, _closed_ interval is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @TonyK right, because a the closed interval is compact, and compact sets are uniformly continuous on their domain.

Comment: You might want to rephrase that $-$ how can a set be continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lvert x+y\rvert\leqslant20$ on $[-10,10]$, you can take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon{20}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my shot at the whole proof:

Given $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary, we must find a single $\delta>0$ where by $|x-y|<\delta$  $=>$ $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Choose $\delta = \epsilon/20$

Now $|f(x)-f(y)| = |x^2-y^2|=|x+y||x-y| \leq 20|x-y| < 20\delta = 20(\epsilon/20)=\epsilon$